How to get info about the certificate which are present in apple developer portal using fastlane
I want to get notificate when the certificate in my apple developer portal is going to expire, so is there way to get the info about the certificate expire date and send email. is there any way in fastlane to get info of certificate.
I have tried to find way in fastlane to get info of all certificate in my developer portal but did not got one , if someone have answer how can we get info of certificate using fastlane or any alternative

Does this help?

What has this to do with Python?
